# How to make Login Form processing into php functions

Tags: php

I got this login form, I want to make the processing of the php in the function.
Example, if am clear

HTML FORM

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/index.php" class="loginform">
        <p>
            <label for="user_login">Username<br>
            <input type="text" name="log" id="user-name" class="input" value="" size="20"></label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="user_pass">Password<br>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user-pass" class="input" value="" size="20"></label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="login-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log In">
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect-to" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="hook" value="admin_login">
            <a href="#" class="forgot-pass">Lost your password?</a>
        </p>                
    </form>
```

So whenever some clicks on the submit button, their should be a function called that will handle the processing.

Example:

```
function login_form(){

}
```

I didn't tired it because am looking for a secure answer from experts on this. Thanks!

Comment: So right a function for it. We aren't here to write code for free, for random people. We're here to help people solve problems they've encountered while trying to do things on their own. Try for yourself, then come back and show us what you tried and we can help you diagnose problems.

Comment: Try, it's a lot easier to help someone once we know what he knows. Try, then ask again. This question is probably going to be closed soon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's up to you. Regardless of how you do it you will have to test the POST data at some point. At that point you could send it off to a function if you wish. If you want to keep things modular and reusable move everything into functions that handle different parts of the validation process.

You can have one function that handles whether the credentials are even valid for testing. Then you can use another function for handling the lookup in the database. You could write a class too which will make things easier for you down the road.

Just drop the POST data into a couple of parameters for your call.

IE:

```
function validate_login($username, $password)
{
   // Your validation code here.
}

if($submitted)
{
  validate_login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what your question is really... but I'm going to try anyway.

> I got this login form, I want to make the processing of the php in the function.

Do you mean that you want to process the POST data with a php function? The subsequent HTML sends the user inputted data to PHP. From PHP, you can do whatever you want, including passing the $_POST["user_login"]  and $_POST["user_login"] variables to functions. See the docs here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

If you want to preprocess the data before PHP gets to it, you can use the onclick="myFunction()" and then define your function in JavaScript. This way you can do whatever you want with the data before it gets to PHP.

Hope that helps.